# jQuery UI Multiple Dialogue's

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a table and for every row I would like to create a dialogue box and a link that can be clicked to launch that dialogue box.

E.g. 
Name 1 (click to get more details). { these are the details for name 1}
Name 2 (click to get more details). { these are the details for name 2}

So I would need a dialogue function that I can pass a custom title and body to... And then call that on the click of a link  Click here to launch dialogue

I hope I have made myself clear.

Many Thanks, 
JPH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you asked for:

```
<DIV id="MyDialog">

</DIV>

<SCRIPT>
    $(function() {
        $("#MyDialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
    });

    function showdialog (title, body) {
        $("#MyDialog").html(body);
        $("#MyDialog").dialog("option", "title", title);
        $("#MyDialog").dialog('open');
    }

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I have this: 
 
DO UNTIL rsRetrievePersonalStatementsAwaitingModeration.EOF
        personalStatement = rsRetrievePersonalStatementsAwaitingModeration("Body")
        %>
         <!-- Dialogue Call Start -->
          <DIV id="MyDialog">

          </DIV>

          <a href="callDialogue(<%=rsRetrievePersonalStatementsAwaitingModeration("Body") %>)"> Click for more details </a>
         <!-- Dialogue Call End --> 
        <%
        rsRetrievePersonalStatementsAwaitingModeration.MoveNext
        indexVariable = indexVariable + 1
LOOP

Do you see my Dilema?

Comment: Place the <DIV id="MyDialog"> outside the loop! After document is loaded ($(function() {...});) it's turned into a dialog (but kept hidden, hence autoOpen: false, until you need it). This dialog is (re-)used every time a user clicks.

Comment: Hey - I realise that the code wont work - its just a bit of Pseudo coding. Right so if I have the div outside of the loop - how would I change the value of the dialogue box?

Thanks for your help thus far, JPH

Comment: Well, it's more than pseudo but you indeed need to integrate it into your own code. So the <DIV> should be somewhere within in your <BODY> tag. The <SCRIPT> you can place inside your <HEAD> tag, perhaps you already have a <SCRIPT> tag there, maybe you even have a $(function() {}) already, you can integrate the 2 then. And for your question: now you can show a dialog by calling the JavaScript function like this: showDialog('Just a title', 'Body, blabla can be HTML blabla'). For instance, you can do this by changing the href to: href="javascript:dialog('<% somestuff %>', '<%some more stuff%>')

Comment: Hello, We are really getting there, this: "showDialog('Just a title', 'Body, blabla can be HTML blabla')." is exactly what I require... and would this be able to handle HTML characters?

Now I then add : "<a href="href="javascript:dialog('<%= titleVariable %>', '<%=bodyVariable%>"..., I understand but do I still require a div even though I am passing the values through Javascript?

Comment: Yes, you still need the `div` that the dialog will use. This has to either already exist in your code, or get created via javascript prior to calling the dialog on it. I also suggest that you use something like http://jsfiddle.net/ to show your code (changes) rather than trying to show through comments (as they are quite hard to read).

Comment: Hey guys - I have got it figured. Many Thanks for the assistance.